# Auto columns HTML

Tags: html

I wonder if it is possible to create auto columns with HTML and PHP.

I am currently using something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      key1: value1<br />
      key2: value2<br />
      key3: value3<br />
    </td>
    <td>
      key4: value4<br />
      key5: value5<br />
      key6: value6<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to combine both rows within one PHP loop, therefore I would like to have a structure like this (but able to generate not only one, but two rows instead):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      key1: value1<br />
      key2: value2<br />
      key3: value3<br />
      key4: value4<br />
      key5: value5<br />
      key6: value6<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are hardcoding in the values you can use two columns like follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>key1: value1</td>
      <td>key4: value4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>key2: value2</td>
      <td>key5: value5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>key3: value3</td>
      <td>key6: value6</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

this will put your answers like the follows:

```
key1: value1      key4: value4
key2: value2      key5: value5
```

If you want to dynamically do your columns and have half and half you can use the following php. It takes would take two for loops but would get you what you want.

```
<td>
   <?php for($i = 1; $i <= (sizeof($data)/2); $i++) {
             print $data[$i] + "<br/>";
         } 
   ?>
</td>
<td>
   <?php for($i = (sizeof($data)/2) + 1; $i <= sizeof($data); $i++) {
             print $data[$i] + "<br/>";
         } 
   ?>
</td>
```

Comment: but what i have to do if i use for example: for($i=1;i<sizeof($data);$i++)... ?

Comment: take a look at the bottom part that I just added

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the *best* way to do this is to use your original markup with the 2 columns.  Even if you find some css trick to eliminate the second column, you will most likely need to disorder the key/value pairs to make them display how you want. What I mean is that if you want this:

```
key1:val1  |  key4:val4  |
key2:val2  |  key5:val5  |
key3:val3  |  key6:val6  |
```

You would need to code this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
      key1: value1<br />
      key4: value4<br />
      key2: value2<br />
      key5: value5<br />
      key3: value3<br />
      key6: value6<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Which would be a total mess. Perhaps there is another way to acheive your goal?

Answer (score 0):

A more dynamic one with configurable amount of colmuns:

```
$columns = 4; // Change to whatever you want

$aData['key1'] = 'col A';
$aData['key2'] = 'col B';
$aData['key3'] = 'col C';
$aData['key4'] = 'col D';
$aData['key5'] = 'col E';
$aData['key6'] = 'col F';
$aData['key7'] = 'col G';
$aData['key8'] = 'col H';
$aData['key9'] = 'col I';
$aData['key10'] = 'col J';

$aColumns = [];
foreach( $aData as $key => $value ) {
    $aColumns[] = $key . ": " . $value;
}

$count_columns = count( $aColumns );

// by row
$current_row = 0;
echo "<table border='1'>";
while( ($current_row)*$columns < $count_columns ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $offset = $current_row *$columns;

    for( $col = 0; $col < $columns; $col++ ) {
        echo "<td>";    
        echo $aColumns[$col +$offset] ?? "";
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $current_row++;
}
echo "</table>";

echo "<hr>";

// or by Col
$count_rows = ceil( $count_columns /$columns );
echo "<table border='1'>";
for( $row = 0; $row < $count_rows; $row++ ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for( $col = 0; $col < $columns; $col++ ) {
        echo "<td>";    
        echo $aColumns[$row +($col*$count_rows) ] ?? "";
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $current_row++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

**OUTPUT**

```html
<table border="1"><tbody><tr><td>key1: col A</td><td>key2: col B</td><td>key3: col C</td><td>key4: col D</td></tr><tr><td>key5: col E</td><td>key6: col F</td><td>key7: col G</td><td>key8: col H</td></tr><tr><td>key9: col I</td><td>key10: col J</td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
<hr>
<table border="1"><tbody><tr><td>key1: col A</td><td>key4: col D</td><td>key7: col G</td><td>key10: col J</td></tr><tr><td>key2: col B</td><td>key5: col E</td><td>key8: col H</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>key3: col C</td><td>key6: col F</td><td>key9: col I</td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```